# How I can use socket on this code?

Tags: android, android-studio

**I want to establish connection between my android client and PC server**.

But my knowledge in Socket is not yet enough, maybe someone can help me with this code what are the codes I need to add. I have a button named connect that will create a connection between the pc server and mobile client if you pressed it. Then there will be a log message if its successfull or not. I hope someone can help me.

**Here is my code:**

```
package ph.roprovider.connection;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code has zero socket implementation. You might want to read more into it e.g. start with the Android Bluetooth developer guides. There is some description about socket handling. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Answer (score 0):

You learn more Socket io or another Socket libraries

http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android

Comment: But look like it doesnt have IP and Port in this guide. What I am looking for is how I can connect to a running console server ip and ports.